# Why does passing null dispatch to constructor with arguments in Java?

Tags: java, dispatch

Given these baby classes

```
public class Domain<V> {
    public Domain(V v) {} // (1)
    public Domain() {}    // (2)
}
```

and

```
public class User {}
```

and a client

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Domain<User> d1 = new Domain<>(new User());
        Domain<User> d2 = new Domain<>(null);
    }
}
```

Which constructor is it going to hit, (1) or (2)?

Spoiler: its one

What's the story behind that? It implies, that `null` is while effectively nothing, still an argument or what?

Comment: Add some print info and check for yourself.

Comment: I can see where its going, but I dont understand why. It's essentially matching `null` to `V`, which surprises me. Is that's what is happening?

Comment: `null` is something. It is the empty value of a reference type. What if you did this. `User nu = null;` Then you called 'new Domain<>(nu);` which one would you expect it to call? When you call `new Domain<>(null);` it will use a constructor with a single argument. It doesn't know what null is so it needs other information to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more intuitive, try to look at it this way:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = getUserFromSomewhere(); // This potentially returns null!
        Domain<User> d1 = new Domain<>(user);
        Domain<User> d2 = new Domain<>(null);
    }
}
```

Doesn't matter if the `user` is actually null or not (let's imagine we don't know it), for Java, it will always mean to run the constructor (1), because `null` is still a value, even though it semantically means 'nothing'. You can imagine this as passing a an integer `0` to some function.

Besides, your constructor could potentially have logic like this:

```java
public class Domain<V> {
    public Domain(V v) {
        if (v == null)
            System.out.println("Hello");
        else
            System.out.println("World");
    }
    public Domain() {} 
}
```

If Java were to run the second constructor instead, you wouldn't be able to use such logic.

Comment: The important thing to me is `null is still a value`.

Comment: Yes `null` is a valid value and compiler matches up the method by arguments, otherwise you are implying that JVM should make a runtime choice between `someMethod(a,b,c)` and `someMethod(b)` based on checking the passed in values - and what do you call if a/b/c were all null?